# Synchronize multiple requests to database in NestJS

Tags: node.js, postgresql, transactions, nestjs, typeorm

in our NestJS application we are using TypeORM as ORM to work with db tables and `typeorm-transactional-cls-hooked` library.

now we have problem with synchronization of requests which are read and modifying database at same time.

Sample:

```
@Transactional()
async doMagicAndIncreaseCount (id) {
    const await { currentCount } = this.fooRepository.findOne(id)

    // do some stuff where I receive new count which I need add to current, for instance 10
    const newCount = currentCount + 10
    

    this.fooRepository.update(id, { currentCount: newCount })
}
```

When we executed this operation from the frontend multiple times at the same time, the final count is wrong. The first transaction read `currentCount` and then start computation, during computation started the second transaction, which read `currentCount` as well, and first transaction finish computation and save new `currentCount`, and then also second transaction finish and rewrite result of first transaction.

Our goal is to execute this operation on `foo` table only once at the time, and other requests should wait until.

I tried set SERIALIZABLE isolation level like this:

```
@Transactional({ isolationLevel: IsolationLevel.SERIALIZABLE })
```

which ensure that only one request is executed at time, but other requests failed with error. Can you please give me some advice how to solve that?

Comment: Maybe queues can solve this. But it's just an idea, I'm having problems with transactions too.

Comment: "do some stuff where..."  What kind of stuff?  Things that depend on currentCount?  Things that depend on "id"?

Comment: @jjanes yes, some business logic which use current count

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never used TypeORM and moreover you are hiding the DB engine you are using.

Anyway to achieve this target you need *write locks*.

The `doMagicAndIncreaseCount` pseudocode should be something like

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
ACQUIRE WRITE LOCK ON id
READ id RECORD
do computation
SAVE RECORD
CLOSE TRANSACTION
```

Alternatively you have to use some operation which is natively atomic on the DB engine; ex. the `INCR` operation on Redis.

**Edit:**

Reading on [TypeORM find](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/find-options.md) documentation, I can suggest something like:

```
this.fooRepository.findOne({
    where: { id },
    lock: { mode: "pessimistic_write", version: 1 },
})
```

P.S. Looking at the tags of the question I would guess the used DB engine is PostgreSQL.